# JavaScript/jQuery Force Tab Key to Skip Field On Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic table. The last item on a row is an href that is used to delete a row. If the user presses the tab key in the field before the last item, a new row is created. This works fine. But I need the cursor to go to the first field in the new row. I cannot focus on the first field in the new row. The cursor simply goes to the href delete button

Here is the HTML and PHP. The form may first be filled from a database table. Thus, the original ItemCount $i variable.

***The function in question is under "EndCell Keypress"***

So, you have here the initial row and possible additional rows on initialization.

```
<div class="parent-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="FieldA(0)" name="FieldA[0]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="Field(0)B" id="FieldB[0]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="FieldC(0)" name="FieldC[0]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="FieldD(0)" name="FieldD[0]" />
        </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <a class="RowDeleteButton del" id="DeleteRow" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<?PHP
$ItemCount = count($FieldC);
if(!empty($_REQUEST['i']) || $ItemCount > 1)
{
    for($i=1;$i<$ItemCount;$i++)
    {
        echo('
        <div class="child-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="FieldA('.$i.')" name="FieldA['.$i.']" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="FieldB('.$i.')" name="FieldB['.$i.']" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="FieldC('.$i.')" name="FieldC['.$i.']" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="FieldD('.$i.')" name="FieldD['.$i.']" class="EndCell" data-datarow='.$i.'/>
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group">
                <a class="RowDeleteButton del Row'.$i.'" id="DeleteRow" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
            </div>
        </div>   
        ');
    }
}
?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#DeleteRow').closest('.form-group').hide();
    // ======================================== //
    //           I T E M S  L I S T             //
    // ======================================== //
    <?PHP
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['i']) || $ItemCount > 0)
    {
        echo('window.LastArrayValue = '.(count($FieldC)-1).';'."\n");
    }
    else
    {
        echo('window.LastArrayValue = 0;'."\n");
    }
    ?>
    // ======================================== //
    //       C R E A T E  N E W  R O W          //
    // ======================================== //
    function CreateNewRow()
    {
        var len = window.LastArrayValue;
        window.LastArrayValue = len + 1;
        $('.parent-group').clone(true, true).find(':input').each(function(idx, ele)
        {
            var ename = ele.name;
            var eid   = ele.id
            var ArrayValue = len+1;
            ele.name = ename.replace(/(\[\/?[^\]]*\])/g, "["+ArrayValue+"]");
            ele.id   = eid.replace(/(\(\/?[^\]]*\))/g, "("+ArrayValue+")");
            if(ele.type == "checkbox"){ele.checked = false;}
            else{ele.value = '';}
        }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
          .toggleClass('parent-group child-group').hide()
          .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');
    }
    // ======================================== //
    //              A D D  R O W                //
    // ======================================== //
    $('#AddRow').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var ChildCount = $('.child-group').length;
        if(ChildCount == 7)
        {
            alert("Sorry, 8 is the maximum number of rows");
        }
        else
        {
            CreateNewRow();
        }
    });
    // ======================================== //
    //           D E L E T E  R O W             //
    // ======================================== //
    $('.del').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var jsonData = $(this).closest('.child-group, .parent-group')
        .find(':input:not(button)').get()
        .reduce(function(acc, ele)
        {
           acc[ele.name || ele.id] = ele.value;
           return acc;
        }, {});
        $(this).closest('.child-group, .parent-group').remove();
    });
    // ======================================== //
    //     E N D C E L L  K E Y P R E S S       //
    // ======================================== //
    $('.EndCell').on('keydown', function(e)
    {
        var KeyCode = e.keyCode;
        if(KeyCode == 9)
        {
            var DataRow = $(this).data("datarow");
            var ChildCount = $('.child-group').length;
            if(DataRow == ChildCount && ChildCount < 7)
            {
                CreateNewRow();
                var V = "FieldD("+window.LastArrayValue+")";
                $("#"+V).focus();
            }   
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `(` and `)` have a special meaning in CSS, so if you want to use them in a selector  and have their literal meaning, you need to escape them. Prefxing them with a backslash each should be enough in this instance. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: @04FS Thanks! That appears to have solved that problem.

Comment: Which part of the second issue are you struggling with in particular? Is recognizing the tab key press in the right location not working? Finding the right field to set the focus to? Something else?

Comment: In $("#FieldA(x)").focus();, the definition now seems to be coming out correctly, but it is not focusing on that field.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a `preventDefault` call when handling the `keydown` event? If the default action of pressing the tab key is not prevented, it might “undo” your attempt at setting focus elsewhere directly afterwards.

Comment: Tried putting e.preventDefault inside the brackets under if(KeyCode == 9). Made no difference.

Comment: That field is created by the call to `CreateNewRow` inside the event handler? Then it might be a sort of “timing” issue perhaps. Does `$("#"+V)` point actually find the field? Does it help if you wrap setting the focus into a short setTimeout call with a couple of milliseconds delay?

Comment: Tried using setTimeout before. Just tried again to no avail. The is something else happening, though. I am now getting Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #FieldA\\(1). (no backslashing showing on 2nd parentheses) Rechecked backslashes - seem to be okay. Going to have to rest on this until Tomorrow (I mean later today). I'll try to make a fiddle or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The dynamic fields use parentheses (eg: FieldName(1)), depending on the row number. This produces Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #FieldName(3)

`(` and `)` have a special meaning in CSS, so if you want to use them in a selector and have their literal meaning, you need to escape them. (More details on that can be found under https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) This applies to places where you use CSS selectors with JavaScript or jQuery methods as well.

Prefixing them with a backslash, `\(` and `\)`, should be enough in this instance.

**Rabbit:**
Here's the solution.
Added the class "FirstCell" to FieldA
Changes the line

.appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow');

To

```
.appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow',function()
{
    $("#container").find(".FirstCell").last().focus();
});
```

Comment: Of course, the main problem still remains. I probably should have split this into two questions, but I didn't know whether they were related or not.

Comment: Ignore above comment. Answer was edited to complete the solution.

Comment: The discussion concerning parentheses and backslashes is irrelevant. That was not the problem causing the error...